# Angular 8: Observable.subscribe Makes my user class empty

Tags: angular, angular8

I am new to Angular. I make a call to API

```
GetUserDetailsfromID(id:number):Observable<UserResponse> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");        
    return this.http.get<UserResponse>(this.baseUrl + "Users/GetById/" + id, this.getOptions());
}
```

and form repository class I am making a call

```
GetUserDetailsfromID(id:number) {   
    this.dataSource.GetUserDetailsfromID(id).subscribe( x => {
           this.userresp = x;
           console.log(this.userresp);//**Here i am  able to view data**
         });
     var data = this.userresp; 
     console.log(data); //**but this becomes undefined always**
     return  this.userresp;
}
```

Can any body help please...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscribe to observable is returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769042/subscribe-to-observable-is-returning-undefined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 8 How to get value from observable in ngOnInit and how do they behave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650530/angular-8-how-to-get-value-from-observable-in-ngoninit-and-how-do-they-behave)

Answer (score 2):

It is asynchronous, so you have to put it into the subscribe block. It is not possible to assign it outside of the block, since the subscription doesn't wait and it continues. That's why it is undefined.

```
GetUserDetailsfromID(id:number) {   
    this.dataSource.GetUserDetailsfromID(id).subscribe(x => {
        this.userresp = x;
        console.log(this.userresp);
        var data = this.userresp; 
    });
}
```

Usually async data is handled like this:

TS

```
GetUserDetailsfromID(id:number): Observable<any> {   
    return this.dataSource.GetUserDetailsfromID(id);
}
```

HTML

```
{{ GetUserDetailsfromID() | async }}
```

#### I highly recommend you to take a look at the introduction page of rxjs:

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview

Answer (score 1):

HttpCall is asynchronous, tou will get the result only after subscribing it, not outside the block

Comment: after subscribing too i get empty userresp class

Answer (score 0):

Thats because of when `this.userresp` has loaded value is undefined and it called by first before any `.subscribe()` is called... so you have to put your code like this in completion stage of subscription...

```
GetUserDetailsfromID(id:number) {   
    this.dataSource.GetUserDetailsfromID(id).subscribe( x => {
            this.userresp = x;
            console.log(this.userresp);//**Here i am  able to view data**
         },

         (err) => {}, // Error Stage...

         () => {  // Completion stage is gets called when observable completes.
                  var data = this.userresp; 
                  console.log(data); //**but this becomes undefined always**
                  return  this.userresp;                 
          });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurang.. but still i am not able to get data in my component from repository

Comment: what is the use of `var data` ?

Comment: nothing just checking what i get will be consoled or not

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Every One for posting your answers 
My Problem soled by below code

'

```
public GetUserDetailsfromID(id:number): Promise<any>
    {   
        return this.dataSource.GetUserDetailsfromID(id).toPromise();
    }
```

'

and in constructor i call like below

'

```
async getuserdata()
  {
    this.userid = localStorage.getItem("userid")

    this.data = await this.repo.GetUserDetailsfromID(Number(this.userid))
    this.user.Id = this.data["id"];
    this.user.FirstName = this.data["firstName"];
    this.user.LastName = this.data["lastName"];
    this.user.Username = this.data["username"];
    this.user.Mobilenumber = this.data["mobilenumber"];

    console.log(this.user);
  }
```

'

I dont know it this the best way but it solves my problem for now...

Thanks again for you valuable time

Regards,

Comment: This will block your thread. Later on when your application grows it will bring a bad user experience when the app stucks while loading.